# AppBarLayout and Toolbar set no shadow

Tags: android

I have `AppBarLayout` and `Toolbar` in acitivty and `TabLayout` into my Fragment. How can I set my toolbar shadow to zero so it would be smooth place between toolbar and tablayout?

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    android:theme="@style/SDK.Theme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        local:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the shadow programatically.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {            
    appBar.setElevation(0);
}
```

Where `appBar` is your `AppBarLayout`.

EDIT:

I've just noticed you use `android:elevation="0dp"` attribute. Use `app:elevation="0dp"` if you want to do it via xml.

Comment: I don't understand where I was wrong but setting this with either app: or android: doesn't help but setting it with code helps

Comment: app: should be used as AppBarLayout is in the support library. But I don't know why it doesn't work for you that way.

Answer (score 0):

This also works if you wanna try.

```
appBarLayout.isEnabled = false
```